# Setting PHP version of command lilne

Tags: php, windows, powershell

I'm using powershell for windows and trying to temporarily run scripts from powershell with PHP 7 but it's stuck on 5.5

I've run `set PATH=%PATH%;"C:\Program Files (x86)\PHP\7.0"` but when I do `php -v` it's still 5.5 for some reason

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check your path that the 5.5 version isn't in there. If it isn't, then close the window and reopen it.

Comment: You may need to relaunch your shell to have your new path actually refreshed

Comment: You appended to a PATH variable that presumably already contained an entry for the PHP 5 dir, so as long as you don’t change the order in which those two appear, it will still find the PHP 5 dir first.

Comment: @misorude that makes sense but I do need 5.5 to be there for other scripts, so can I just use 7 for this command only?

Comment: Don’t rely on the path variable then, but use the complete path to the v7 php.exe on the command line …? (This might not work, if what you are executing in turn tries to run other PHP scripts, or something like that. But before you go for more complex solutions, try the simplest things first …)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Windows 10, it would be much easier to do this from windows explorer.

- Press `Windows + R` to bring up the run window
- Type in `sysdm.cpl` and press enter, this will bring up System properties
- Go to advanced tab, and you'll see `Environment variables` button near the bottom of the page click on the button
- You'll see system variables on the new dialog, look of the variable named `Path` and double click on it, This will show you the list of Paths on your computer
- Look for the one with php on it, this is the variable used to search for your php executable, You can delete if there are multiple of those and keep the one you need, or add on to your will
- Press Ok on all open dialogs
- Open up a new powershell window and type `php -v` to check

If you need both versions, add both paths to the Path variables, make sure the one you want as `php` command is before the other one, 
Then go to the folder containing php5.5, find php.exe, make a copy and rename it to php5.exe, this way you can access php 5.5 as `php5 -v` and php 7 as `php -v`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way I found is to use aliases to temporary switch between php versions from cmd and powershell.

example:

> **`>alias set php Y:\php_binaries\php-5.3.9-Win32-VC9-x86\php.exe`**

of course you have to change the php binary path to match your system.